# SQL SERVER 2008 select statement with case

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, vb6, recordset

I have a Select statement in my VB6 application....

Here's what it looks like.....

```
Dim str As string

str = "SELECT CompID, Department from tblCompanies " & _ 
      "Where CompID in (123, 234, 345, 456) " & _
      "Order by CompID "
```

So what I'm tryign to do here is add a CASE WHEN statement to WHERE clause - basically I'm looking to add a string to each Department name, depending on the COMPID. So I need to specify that these are the COMPID's that I want to select, then I want to do soemthing like

```
 Case when CompID = 123 Then ----ADD "GC" to that Department Name
```

I guess I need to do this before I open my recordset with

```
rs.open str, g_CN, adOpenStatic
```

Because once it's open it seems to be giving me errors when I try to edit it.

All in all, if my recordset looks like this...

```
Accounting
Finance
IT
R&D
```

I'm trying to make it look like

```
"GC" - Accounting
"GC" - Finance
"BP" - IT
"DC" - R&D
```

Comment: So do you actually need to filter on this? The way I'm reading it is that you just want this in the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it to,

```
Dim str As string

str = "SELECT CompID, CASE WHEN CompID IN (123,234) THEN 'GC' " & _
                " WHEN CompID = 345 THEN 'IT' " & _
                " WHEN CompID = 456 THEN 'DC' " & _
                " ELSE '' END + ' - ' + Department AS Department from tblCompanies " & _ 
      "Where CompID in (123, 234, 345, 456) " & _
      "Order by CompID "
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str = "SELECT CompID, CASE WHEN CompID = 123 THEN '""GC"" - ' ELSE '' END + Department  As Department from tblCompanies " & _ 
      "Where CompID in (123, 234, 345, 456) " & _
      "Order by CompID "
```

Comment: pelase see edit, Thank you! it seems a bit harder than I thought